# RxJava and Retrofit Chain multiple Calls from diffrent Services and Conditions

Tags: java, android, rest, rx-java, retrofit2

i don´t get the right way. The Problem is, that i have two Retrofit API´s and Services and need two wait for response and make a decision and based on this other calls.

Example:

APIx:

```
@GET("xyz/{id}/exists")
Observable<Exists> checkObjectExists(@Path("id") String id);

@POST("xyz/")
Observable<Object> addObjectA(@Body Object a);
```

APIy:

```
@POST("abc/{id}/blabla")
Observable<Object> addObjectB(@Path("id") String id, @Body Object b);
```

Now the Use case:

I need to do a Request if some Object exists like:

```
serviceA.exists(id).flatMap(exists -> if(exists) ...
```

if Exists is true then i need to call

```
serviceB.addObjectB(b)
```

Then the first flow is finish.

if Exists is false i need to call

```
serviceA.addObject(a)
```

and then when the i get a Success in onNext i need to call

```
ServiceB.addObject(b)
```

again. But i really dont get the Chain with RxJava and Retrofit. I can handle this stuff with a lot lines of Code with something like this:

```
    private void _checkExists() {
    ServiceA serviceA= ServiceA.create();
    serviceA.checkObjectExists(id)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Exists>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Timber.d("Something get Wrong");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Exists exists) {
                    if(exists) {
                        _addObjectB(b);
                    } else {
                        addobjectA(a);
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void addObjectA(Object a) {
    ServiceA serviceA= ServiceA.create();
    serviceA.addObjectA(a)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Timber.d("Something get Wrong");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Object a) {
                    addObjectB();
                }
            });
}

private void addObjectB() {
    ServiceB serviceB= ServiceB .create();
    serviceB.addObjectB(id, b)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Timber.d("Something get Wrong");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Object b) {
                    Timber.d("Everything is ok");
                }
            });
}
```

I tried to chain everything together with flatMap and so on, but it works not correctly in the Chain and also the ErrorHandling was strange, because when i get some Error from the Backend my app will Crash, this is why i add every call the Action3 with OnComplete,OnError,OnNext. Is there a possibility to do this with less code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you try with `flatMap` ?

regarding your code, it seams that you call `checkObjectExists` then, depending of the result `addObjectA` then `addObjectB` or only `addObjectB`.

So, it can be achieve like this :

```
 ServiceA serviceA= ServiceA.create();
 ServiceA serviceB= ServiceB.create();

 serviceA.checkObjectExists(id)
         .flatMap(exists -> {
                if(exists) {
                    return serviceB.addObjectB(id, b)
                } else {
                    return serviceA.addObjectA(id, a).flatMap(newA -> serviceB.addObject(id, newA);
                }

         })
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe();
```

(as it miss some part of your code, it's hard to undertand from where `a`, `b` and other variables come from.

As you can see, it only rely on `flatMap` and may be closed to what you already try.

Comment: What does this mean: y A/art: art/runtime/barrier.cc:90] Check failed: count_ == 0 (count_=-1, 0=0) Attempted to destroy barrier with non zero count
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Runtime aborting --- recursively, so no thread-specific detail!
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] 
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 20983

Comment: don't know. I do not develop on Android.